# Display creation date (created_at) in post in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Good morning guys, I'm a good beginner in laravel and I have a small problem that I can not solve. In viewing a post, I need to display the date the post was created. In the database would be the column created_at (timestamp format). But I do not know why, this field is printing a null result. Can anyone tell me how to solve this? I was trying to use it like this:

```
{{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($noticia->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

But the above code just displays the current date, I believe on account that the field $ noticia-> created_at is coming null;

Here is the complete site code:

**Model**

```
namespace App\Models;        
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
    use App\Traits\Sluggable;

    class Post extends Model
    {
        use Sluggable;
        protected static $sluggable = 'titulo';
        public static $storage      = 'post';
        protected $table            = 'post';
        protected $dates            = ['periodo_inicio', 'periodo_fim', 'created_at', 'updated_at'];
        protected $fillable         = [
            'id', 'titulo', 'conteudo', 'periodo_inicio', 'periodo_fim', 'imagem', 'qtd_views',
            'active', 'destaque', 'slug', 'resumo', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'title_seo', 'description_seo'
        ];
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public function noticiasDetalhe($slug)
    {
        $base_posts_destaques = Post::where('active', 1)->where('destaque', 1)->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(4)->get();

        $noticia = Post::where('slug', $slug)->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')->first();

        $buscar = '';
        $page_title = '';
        $page_description = '';

        if($noticia) {

            $noticia->update(['qtd_views'=>($noticia->qtd_views + 1)]);
            if($noticia->title_seo != "") {
                $page_title = $noticia->title_seo . " - Berkan";
            } else {
                $page_title = $noticia->titulo . " - Berkan";
            }

            if($noticia->description_seo != "") {
                $page_description = $noticia->description_seo . " - Berkan";
            } else {
                $page_description = $noticia->resumo . " - Berkan";
            }

            $categorias = Post_Categoria::where('active', 1)->get();

            $base_posts = Post::where('post_rel_categorias.post_categoria_id', $noticia->post_categoria_id)
                ->where('post_rel_categorias.id', '<>', $noticia->id)
                ->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')
                ->select(
                    'post_rel_categorias.id',
                    'post_rel_categorias.post_id',
                    'post.id',
                    'post.titulo',
                    'post.imagem',
                    'post.slug',
                    'post.created_at'
            )->orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)->get();

        } else {
            abort(404);
            die();
        }

        return view('noticias-detalhe', compact('noticia', 'base_posts_destaques', 'base_posts', 'categorias', 'page_title', 'page_description'));
    }
```

If anyone knows how to solve this, thank you.

**print dd($noticia)**

```
Post {#419 ▼
  #table: "post"
  #dates: array:4 [▼
    0 => "periodo_inicio"
    1 => "periodo_fim"
    2 => "created_at"
    3 => "updated_at"
  ]
  #fillable: array:15 [▼
    0 => "id"
    1 => "titulo"
    2 => "conteudo"
    3 => "periodo_inicio"
    4 => "periodo_fim"
    5 => "imagem"
    6 => "qtd_views"
    7 => "active"
    8 => "destaque"
    9 => "slug"
    10 => "resumo"
    11 => "created_at"
    12 => "updated_at"
    13 => "title_seo"
    14 => "description_seo"
  ]
  #connection: "mysql"
  #primaryKey: "id"
  #keyType: "int"
  +incrementing: true
  #with: []
  #withCount: []
  #perPage: 15
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
  #attributes: array:18 [▼
    "id" => "53"
    "titulo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "slug" => "educacao-profissional-continuada-para-o-auditor-independente"
    "resumo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "conteudo" => ""
    "imagem" => "post/N9kKOUODlFnISmF8pyO8hvJR2nDMWoLHjz5cAcmO.jpeg"
    "periodo_inicio" => null
    "periodo_fim" => null
    "active" => "1"
    "destaque" => "0"
    "qtd_views" => "272"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "title_seo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "description_seo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "post_id" => "43"
    "post_categoria_id" => "5"
  ]
  #original: array:18 [▼
    "id" => "53"
    "titulo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "slug" => "educacao-profissional-continuada-para-o-auditor-independente"
    "resumo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶" 
    "imagem" => "post/N9kKOUODlFnISmF8pyO8hvJR2nDMWoLHjz5cAcmO.jpeg"
    "periodo_inicio" => null
    "periodo_fim" => null
    "active" => "1"
    "destaque" => "0"
    "qtd_views" => "272"
    "deleted_at" => null
    "created_at" => null
    "updated_at" => null
    "title_seo" => "Educação profissional continuada para o auditor independente"
    "description_seo" => "Como uma forma de valorizar a profissão do contador diante da sociedade e das empresas, o Conselho Federal de Contabilidade (CFC) estabeleceu a norma de educaçã ▶"
    "post_id" => "43"
    "post_categoria_id" => "5"
  ]
  #changes: []
  #casts: []
  #dateFormat: null
  #appends: []
  #dispatchesEvents: []
  #observables: []
  #relations: []
  #touches: []
  +timestamps: true
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▼
    0 => "*"
  ]
}
```

Thank you

Comment: try {{ Carbon\Carbon::parse($noticia[0]->created_at)->format('d/m/Y') }}

Comment: you don't need to add created_at and updated_at in $dates or $fillable, they are added by default. Can you add the result of this in your answer {{ dd($noticia) }}? just put that code in your blade.

Comment: Hello @Indra I updated my question with the printing of the dd($noticia) screen. Could you see if you could help me?

Comment: Your created_at field is null, that why is not working.Add public $timestamps = true; in Post model. Also remove created_at and updated_at from $dates array in model. They are added by default. also the table name should be posts and you should not add it in model ideally. Try adding a new post and see if created at is null for the new post after making the changes. Check directly in the database. Also do you have any accesors/mutators on created_at/updated_at in your model?

Comment: Hello @Indra I found the problem. The problem is in the following line of Controller: "$noticia = Post::where('slug', $slug)->leftjoin('post_rel_categorias', 'post_rel_categorias.post_id', '=', 'post.id')->first();"
The problem is in leftjoin, because there are two tables with the name of the same field: created_at. This is causing the created_at field to return null

Answer (score 2):

Remove your created_at and updated_at from $dates and $fillable
In blade simply print out

```
{{ $noticia->created_at->format('d/m/Y') }}
```

Comment: Hello @colorscream, Unfortunately it did not work. The created_at field is returning null

Comment: this is the right answer, however your filed is null in the database so you need to figure out why it's inserting null. How do you save the post in the db?

Comment: Take a look at this, too: `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')->take(3)`.  It likely orders the nulll values first.

Comment: If you have empty values in created_at and updated_at then you have to check them before formating `{{ $noticia->created_at ? $noticia->created_at->format('d/m/Y') : null }}`